Self defence and internet laws basically
If Mrs A posts a joke on TikTok about using a deodorant spray as self defense, would that be termed illegal in the uk

To answer this question one would need to know the jurisdiction. Things like this change from place to place. Also, things which may be legal if they are not premediated may become illegal if premediated, and so the details of your statement would matter.

Why would a joke be illegal?

@Barmar, because the legal system might take the statement at face value rather than as a joke, and it might have been a public announcement of a planned violent act. Or not, depending on the exact words and context.

@o.m. So Henny Youngman could have been arrested for soliciting a kidnapping?

Well @o.m. the exact words used were putting the deodorant in the bag in case A has to defend herself because of the ongoing riots with a content disclaimer in the caption

Almost surely not.
Deodorant isn't inherently a deadly or restricted weapon (although it is sometimes used as a pepper spray substitute), any more than carrying a heavy purse full of ordinary stuff that due to its weight can be used to slug someone is. It is not illegal in the U.K. to carry deodorant on your person.
It is also not illegal to contemplate means of self-defense in public.
If the intent were to use the deodorant not as a variant on pepper spray (as suggested, e.g., here), but as a primitive flame thrower, the social media post might be evidence of pre-mediation in the use of the deodorant in a deadly manner in this fashion, as opposed to a claim that it accidentally ignited.
This could be relevant if the deodorant used as a flame thrower was later used to cause disproportionate harm in self-defense (or used without legal justification). But that wouldn't make the post itself illegal, before any of that happened.
A social media website would be free to restrict posts of this kind through their terms of service or content moderation, but that wouldn't have legal consequences.
